# Does "either" mean one of the two or both of the two in these two sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I learned from other answers that whether "either" means one of the two or both of the two depends on the context. In Sentence 1, "either" has to mean only one of the two income brackets because the same households can't be in two different brackets at the same time.

> 1. Fewer households making **either** $50,000 to $74,999 or $75,000 **to** $99,000 a year.

In sentence 2, "either" could mean only one of the last two years or both of the last two years.

> 2. The number of people affected by the new withdrawals far exceeds the number in **either** of the last two years. In those years, H.M.O.'s pulled out of more than 400 counties in at least 33 states, directly affecting 734,000 Medicare beneficiaries -- 407,000 in 1999 and 327,000 this year. -- [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2000/07/25/us/estimate-of-ousters-by-hmo-s-is-raised.html)

Is my reasoning correct? (I wrote the first sentence myself.)

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks again. In another question, you wrote this sentence: More boys played football than took part in **either** tennis or cycling. Does it mean boys playing football outnumbered boys participating in each of the other two sports or outnumbered boys participating in only one of the other two sports? I was actually just imitating what you wrote. I don't understand why (2) doesn't work.

Comment: @KateBunting: It's incredibly confusing to have two different examples here where the second one *appears* to be part of the same context, but is in fact unrelated! But putting that aside, if we assume #2 applies to some other context with *at least three different ranges*, I think ***both*** is potentially ambiguous. It might mean the *total* households in the two lower ranges *combined* is greater than in the highest range, OR the total ion ***each*** of those lower ranges is greater than in the highest range. There's no such ambiguity with *surpassed by the number in **each** of the two...*

Comment: newbieforever: *Your* examples are confusing because they *appear* to be connected, where in fact they're not. The newspaper article is fine. As per my first comment, ***either*** there unambiguously means ***one of two***. That's to say, the new number is greater than last year's number AND it's greater than the number two years ago.

Comment: Newbie - More boys played football than tennis, and more played football than went cycling. @FumbleFingers - Yes, perhaps _both_ is ambiguous there. It's hard to explain because sentence (2) doesn't seem at all natural.

Comment: I'm not sure whether *The number of households in **either** of the two lowest ranges surpassed the number in the highest range* is syntactically valid or not. But it's totally non-idiomatic. To be natural, you must replace ***either*** by ***both*** or ***each***. As explained in an earlier comment, ***both*** could be ambiguous (it might be understood as meaning *both **combined, added together***). But there's no ambiguity with ***each***, which definitely means there were more in the lowest range than in the highest, AND there were more in the second-to-lowest range than in the highest.

Comment: VALID: 1) *Either of my sons could beat your son* (implies I have exactly two sons) 2) *My daughter is prettier than either of your daughters* (implies you have exactly two daughters) 3) *I have never met either of your daughters*. INVALID / WEIRD: 4) *My daughter likes either of your daughters* 5) *Either of your daughters knows my daughter*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you...you're so nice!

Comment: I know ***either*** and ***neither*** are "difficult". It's rare in BrE, but I sometimes hear Americans say ***Me either*** by way of agreeing with someone who says ***I don't know***. For me, it would *have* to be ***Me neither*** or ***Nor me*** to indicate agreement with a "negated" assertion. Have a look at [this from sadly-no-longer-with-us John Lawler](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) about "negative polarity" items in English.

Comment: I've edited the question to replace the incorrect second example sentence with the unambiguously correct example sentence from the NYT, which holds the additional bonus of not appearing connected to the first example. I've also deleted all the comments relating only to that second sentence. If I've deleted comments that are still of value to improving the quality of this question, please flag as "**In need of moderator intervention**".

Answer (score 0):

Sample sentence:

- Fewer households making either $50,000 to $74,999 or $75,000 to $99,000 a year.
  Typical use of either and or.
- The number of households in the highest income range was surpassed by the number in either of the two lowest ranges.

Please note: the two lowest ranges have to have been mentioned in the previous context. either range = the one or the other, a pronoun in the sample sentence

Merriam Webster:
**either**

2 of 4
**pronoun**
: the one or the other
take either of the two routes

Comment: I don't like the second example *at all*. It'd be fine with "active" ***exceeds*** instead of "passive" ***was surpassed by***, OR it could at least be "improved" by pluralizing the second instance of ***number*** and replacing ***either*** by ***each*** or ***both***. Negative polarity? I dunno.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, of course, one can always do rewrites. The point here was to explain either.